# Cannot add a configuration with name 'testTarget' as a configuration with that name already exists

Tags: android, android-studio

Not able to create a separate test project because of this error. Below is my gradle script.

I tried with the details provided by android developers page. I am trying to create a separate test project all together.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.test'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "olx.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    targetProjectPath ':app'
    targetVariant 'debug'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Can it be that you already have an `androidTest` source set in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Simply removing the following helped me:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```